# MySQL：Cannot create cluster Got Error：The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, innodb, mysql-cluster

I want to create a MySQL cluster (InnoDB) so I create three AWS EC2 Instances (CentOS 7).
When I run `var cluster = dba.createCluster('testCluster');`
I got a Error below：

```
A new InnoDB cluster will be created on instance 'demo@ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306'.

Validating instance at ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306...

This instance reports its own address as ip-172-31-29-118.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal

Instance configuration is suitable.
Creating InnoDB cluster 'testCluster' on 'demo@ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306'...
Dba.createCluster: ERROR: Error starting cluster: 'ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306' - Query failed. MySQL Error (3092): ClassicSession.query: The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log.. Query: START group_replication: MySQL Error (3092): ClassicSession.query: The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log. (RuntimeError)
```

I don't know which part did I wrong. How could I fix it ?
Hope someone could help me.

Here is my steps：

1. Install mysql, mysql shell, mysql router
2. `sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=disabled/g' /etc/sysconfig/selinux`
3. `systemctl stop firewalld & systemctl disable firewalld`
4. `service mysqld start`
5. `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`
6. `mysql -u root -p`
7. `ALTER USER root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'rootpassword';`
   `SET sql_log_bin = 0;`
   `SET @@persist_only.enforce_gtid_consistency='ON';`
   `CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'rootpassword';`
   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
   `CREATE USER 'demo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'demopassword';`
   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.* TO 'demo'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
   `GRANT RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, SUPER, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
   `GRANT SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN, PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
8. `mysqlsh --log-level=DEBUG3`
   `dba.verbose=2`
9. `dba.checkInstanceConfiguration('demo@ec2:3306');`
10. `dba.configureInstance('demo@ec2:3306');`
11. `\c demo@ec2:3306`
12. `var cluster = dba.createCluster('testCluster');`

Here is my log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL Server do you use? Error message tells you to check error log. Did you checked `error.log`? What is in `error.log`?

This information

> Validating instance at ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3306...
>
> This instance reports its own address as ip-172-31-29-118.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal

shows that your instance host and `report_host` are different.

Try to set `report_host` in your MySQL Server configuration to externally visible host  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_report-host), i.e. to `ec2-52-196-251-99.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` or `52.196.251.99`.

Comment: I have add my log.

Comment: What about MySQL Server `error.log`? Have you tried to set `report_host` MySQL Server configuration variable to externally visible IP?